# How to know the fewest numbers we should add to get a full array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math

recently I met a question like this:
Assume you have an int N, and you also have an int[] and each element in this array can only be used once time. And we need to design an algorithm to get 1 to N by adding those numbers and finally return the least numbers we need to add.
For example:

```
N = 6, array is [1,3]
1 : we already have.
2 : we need to add it to the array.
3 : we can get it by doing 1 + 2.
4: 1 + 3.
5 : 2 + 3.
6 : 1 + 2 + 3.
So we just need to add 2 to our array and finally we return 1.
```

I am thinking of solving this by using DFS.
Do you have some better solutions? Thanks!

Comment: i don't know bounds , you can use brute force (not good) , you can make the numbers with at most N/2 numbers , you can prove it , the numbers from 1 ... N/2

Comment: Yeah, I think brute force will works but I am still wondering if there are some better solutions :D

Comment: depends on problems bound , there is a dp solution for this problem

Comment: Coin change problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an explanation for why the solution the OP posted works (the algorithm, briefly, is to traverse the sorted existing elements, keep an accumulating sum of the preceding existing elements and add an element to the array and sum if it does not exist and exceeds the current sum):

The loop tests in order each element that must be formed and sums the preceding elements. It alerts us if there is an element needed that's greater than the current sum. If you think about it, it's really simple! How could we make the element when we've already used all the preceding elements, which is what the sum represents!

In contrast, how do we know that all the intermediate elements will be able to be formed when the sum is larger than the current element? For example, consider `n = 7, a = {}`:

```
The function adds {1,2,4...} 
So we are up to 4 and we know 1,2,3,4 are covered,
each can be formed from equal or lower numbers in the array.

At any point, m, in the traversal, we know for sure that 
X0 + X1 ... + Xm make the largest number we can make, call it Y.
But we also know that we can make 1,2,3...Xm

Therefore, we can make Y-1, Y-2, Y-3...Y-Xm

(In this example: Xm = 4; Y = 1+2+4 = 7; Y-1 = 6; Y-2 = 5)

Q.E.D.
```

Comment: Why do you know that you can cover 1..m if you have m numbers? The sequence mut not necesarily be gap free. In fact knowing/remembering (caching) the sums for sub-sets is part of a efficient solution in dynamic programming.

Comment: @eckes thank you for your comment. At the beginning, if `a` contains `m` numbers, you don't know you can get to `m` when the algorithm starts. By definition of the algorithm, each number is checked in order, one by one. As the algorithm progresses, you cannot get to the number `Xm` if you didn't already get to `Xm-1`. I edited the answer to hopefully clarify a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a good solution or not:

I would create a second array (boolean array) remembering all numbers I can calculate.
Then I would write a method simulating the adding of a number to the array. (In your example the 1, 3 and 2 are added to the array).
The boolean array will be updated to always remember which values (numbers) can be calculated with the added numbers.

After calling the add method on the initial array values, you test for every Number x ( 1 <= x <= N ) if x can be calculated. If not call the add method for x.

since my explanation is no good I will add (untested) Java code:

```
static int[] arr = {3,5};
static int N = 20;
//An Array remembering which values can be calculated so far
static boolean[] canCalculate = new boolean[N];

//Calculate how many numbers must be added to the array ( Runtime O(N^2) )
public static int method(){

    //Preperation (adding every given Number in the array)
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        addNumber(arr[i]);
    }

    //The number of elements added to the initial array
    int result = 0;

    //Adding (and counting) the missing numbers (Runtime O(N^2) )
    for(int i=1; i<=N; i++){
        if( !canCalculate[i-1] ){
            addNumber(i);
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


//This Method is called whenever a new number is added to your array
//runtime O(N)
public static void addNumber( int number ){
    System.out.println("Add Number: "+(number));

    boolean[] newarray = new boolean[N];
    newarray[number-1] = true;

    //Test which values can be calculated after adding this number
    //And update the array
    for(int i=1; i<=N; i++){
        if( canCalculate[i-1] ){
            newarray[i-1] = true;
            if( i + number <= N ){
                newarray[i+number-1] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    canCalculate = newarray;
}
```

Edit: Tested the code and changed some errors (but rachel's solution seems to be better anyway)

Comment: Your solution is much more easily understand! Thanks! Even though the method I found is much more shorter but I can't read that.. LOL

Answer (score 0):

It is a famous problem from dynamic programming. You can refer to complete solution here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6FhG--P7z0

Comment: Thanks for sharing! However there are some differences between those two questions

Comment: It gives you all the possible combinations and then you have to sort them based upon counting of numbers involved in each selection.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a possible solution like this

```
    public static int getNum(int n, int[] a) {
    ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(true) {
        if (i >= a.length || a[i] > sum + 1) {
            output.add(sum + 1);
            sum += sum + 1;
        } else {
            sum += a[i];
            i++;
        }
        if (sum >= n) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return output.size();
};
```

And I test some cases and it looks correct.
But the one who write this didn't give us any hints and I am really confused with this one. Can anybody come up with some explanations ? Thanks!

Comment: does this require an sorted `a[]`?

Comment: I think so, so it should add Arrays.sort(). Thanks!